# Android Specific device deployment

Tags: android

I am trying to deploy an android application on a specific device such as a tablet and I don't want it to be installable on other android devices, is there a way to do that using eclipse?

Is there a way to specify the application bit target for a certain device for android?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, however you can specify in the Android market that you want to disallow all devices except for specific device(s) such as the tablet(s) that you are targeting.

Comment: Thanks Justin, I think it's specified by Android market only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Manifest `AndroidManifest.xml` does not have this information.

As @Justin Shield said, it is only on market configuration.

Maybe newer AAR packaging format will add more metadata about app.